# Will Ubuntu installation on my laptop SSD affect data on an HDD in the same PC?

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, windows, ssd

If I have a SSD with Windows 10 and HDD on my laptop and I want to install Ubuntu on my SSD completely will it affect my HDD's data? Do I need to format and create different partitions of HDD again while installing ubuntu?

Comment: Are you planning to remove Windows completely?

Comment: Yes, I wi\ant to remove windows completely@Pilot6

Answer (score 1):

Installing Ubuntu to your SSD won't affect data on your HDD, but you need to consider a few issues:

1. Your HDD is formatted to NTFS filesystem. It is supported by Ubuntu, but you can't maintain it properly without Windows, like fixing errors, etc. That's why it is highly recommended to backup your data and create a Linux filesystem on your HDD (ext4 or other).
2. Before you remove Windows make sure it is properly shut down. By default when you choose to shut down Windows, it really doesn't. It hibernates making filesystem only partly usable by other OS's. This is called "fast start" feature. ;-)

Comment: How can I convert my NTFS filesystem into the Linux filesystem? Is it a risky process? As I never did installation things ever before! 

Comment: You can't convert. You need to backup your data somwhere else, then create partitions, then copy it back. It is not risky this way at all.

Answer (score 0):

The HDD contents will not be altered if you correctly overwrite the SSD contents in the process of installing Ubuntu on the SSD while following the [official Ubuntu tutorial for installation](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.).

You do not *need* to change the HDD partitioning, although you may *want* to, after completing the Ubuntu installation, to make better use of the HDD. Windows could have put a recovery partition on the HDD, which you may decide you do not need after the Ubuntu install.  You might also decide you wish to repartition the HDD to use a native Linux filesystem instead of NTFS, which is the Windows default, since Ubuntu doesn't have a full selection of tools to fix NTFS filesystem problems.

However, you can continue to read from and write to NTFS and FAT-family file systems on the HDD after you complete the Ubuntu install; see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions for details. That will make it easier for you to copy the contents of the HDD from an NTFS partition to a Linux native partition after the installation.

Comment: If I kept it as it is will it affect the performance of my device as compared to changing it to the required Linux filesystem?

Comment: For comparisons, see https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/bndxkz/yet_another_windows_ntfs_vs_linux_ext4_gnu_quick/  https://www.pcworld.com/article/230527/ubuntu_linux_day_16_ext4_vs_ntfs.html  and https://www.geekboots.com/story/ntfs-vs-ext4-vs-fat32  And, pilot6 is absolutely right about making sure Windows is completely shut down in his point #2 above.

Comment: Thank You! I'll check it out.

Comment: May I also suggest you boot from an Ubuntu LiveUSB, open a terminal, run `sudo parted -l` then go back to your question above, click [edit], and paste the results into your question? It will show us the partitioning of both drives. Since you _must_ copy your data off the HDD _before_ repartitioning from NTFS to Linux native format, it helps to collect the data so we can plan ahead. I keep saying 'native Linux format' and 'Linux filesystem' because you have a choice of which filesystem to use (although I _strongly_ recommend the default choice, _ext4_)..